# NPM installation issues on Mac OS Mavericks

Tags: node.js, angularjs, npm, generator, yeoman

I am trying to get to grips with AngularJS, NodeJS and Ruby on Rails. When trying to install npm packages like yeoman, grunt etc. I receive an error in my Terminal which I have listed below:

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, open '/Users/Jabane/.npm/glob/3.2.11/package/package.json.25961'

npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, open '/Users/Jabane/.npm/glob/3.2.11/package/package.json.25961']

npm ERR!   errno: 3,

npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',

npm ERR!   path: '/Users/Jabane/.npm/glob/3.2.11/package/package.json.25961',

npm ERR!   parent: 'browserify' }

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0

npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "browserify"

npm ERR! cwd /Users/Jabane

npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26

npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.16

npm ERR! path /Users/Jabane/.npm/glob/3.2.11/package/package.json.25961

npm ERR! code EACCES

npm ERR! errno 3

npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, open '/Users/Jabane/.npm/glob/3.2.11/package/package.json.25961'

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:

npm ERR!     /Users/kJabane/npm-debug.log

npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

What might be the issue in this case? Your assistance is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Here is the same problem:

  [npm install problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231846/npm-will-not-install-express)

Answer (score 3):

This is a permissions issue. You need to prefix your npm install command with **[sudo](https://superuser.com/questions/185441/what-does-the-sudo-command-do)**, e.g.:

```
sudo npm install yeoman
```

It will prompt you for your User Account's password; and subject to the correct password being provided, will then install the packages correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt. Got is sorted.

Comment: @kyneticDude Great stuff. Happy it's fixed.