# Yeoman yo karma Issue in configuring

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yo

I'm facing a challenge while adding Karma to the Angular JS generated web app using Yeoman.

When I run `yo karma` then it shows following error:

```
    pdc1-4s6zyr1:ShippingSolutionPlain administrator$ dsenableroot
username = administrator
user password:
root password:
verify root password:

dsenableroot:: ***Successfully enabled root user.
pdc1-4s6zyr1:ShippingSolutionPlain administrator$ sudo yo karma --allow-root
identical test/karma.conf.js
npm WARN package.json shippingsolutionplain@ No repository field.
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/administrator/.npm/karma-jasmine/0.3.5'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/administrator/.npm/karma-jasmine/0.3.5']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/administrator/.npm/karma-jasmine/0.3.5',
npm ERR!   parent: 'shippingsolutionplain' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 11.4.2
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "karma-phantomjs-launcher" "karma-jasmine" "grunt-karma" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolutionPlain
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /Users/administrator/.npm/karma-jasmine/0.3.5
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/administrator/.npm/karma-jasmine/0.3.5'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolutionPlain/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
pdc1-4s6zyr1:ShippingSolutionPlain administrator$
```

Also, Installing the module locally and running it doesn't work.

```
pdc1-4s6zyr1:ShippingSolutionPlain administrator$ sudo yo karma --allow-root
   create test/karma.conf.js
npm WARN package.json shippingsolutionplain@ No repository field.
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolutionPlain/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/.bin/phantomjs'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolutionPlain/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/.bin/phantomjs']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolutionPlain/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/.bin/phantomjs' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 11.4.2
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "karma-phantomjs-launcher" "karma-jasmine" "grunt-karma" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolutionPlain
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolutionPlain/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/.bin/phantomjs
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolutionPlain/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/.bin/phantomjs'
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolutionPlain/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/.bin/phantomjs'
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolutionPlain/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/.bin/phantomjs']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 3,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/Users/administrator/Desktop/CiscoShipping/ShippingSolutionPlain/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/.bin/phantomjs' }
npm ERR! not ok code 0
pdc1-4s6zyr1:ShippingSolutionPlain administrator$
```

Has anyone faced such issue?

Ankit

Comment: possible duplicate of [NPM installation issues on Mac OS Mavericks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24407884/npm-installation-issues-on-mac-os-mavericks)